# MongoDB Upsert not working in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to run an update on my documents, I'm using upsert true but its still overwriting?

```
$col = "A" . $user->agencyID;
$db = $m->rules;
$collection = $db->$col;

$validValue = $_POST['validValue'];
$id = $_POST['ruleID'];

$document = array(
    'tags' => array(
                $validValue
              )
  );


$collection->update(
    array(
      '_id' => new MongoId($id)
      ),
    array('$set' => $document),
    array('upsert'=>true)
);
```

`$validValue` is like - Foo Bar

The first value goes in fine but when I try adding a different value it overwrites the first one?

Comment: What's `$id`? If it's a custom string of some sort and not the a Mongoid, you don't need `new MongoId`.

Comment: @luckytaxi my $id is this - 5704fd6eb23eec37168b4567

Comment: What gets overwritten? Your first value is "Foo Bar" and you update it with "Hello World." What are you expecting?

Comment: @luckytaxi My first value is "Foo Bar" and when I next run this script it should add another element to the array "Hello World" so my 'tags' array would have both these values in.

Comment: Ah, so you don't want `$set` you probaby want `push.` Your current script will update the `tags` field with a new value. `push` will push new values into the array. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/

Comment: @luckytaxi when I use push it creates a new array for every value pushed but I want one array with all the values in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108646/discussion-between-luckytaxi-and-kieron606).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out the problem, I needed [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) and also needed to take the array() from arround my `$validValue`

Comment: Don't add your own answer as an answer to your question.

Comment: @luckytaxi you have tried to steal the answer from me. Don't steal answers, your answer also doesn't work.

Comment: The best part is I mentioned that my code was untested and NO ONE else responded to your question besides me. I was in the middle of researching a solution for you, therefore I had submitted my answer a little after yours. Good luck getting future answers from the community. I sure as heck won't be helping you.

Comment: @luckytaxi I answered my own question. Which SO tells you to do if you worked it out, which I did. You then go look at what I answered then try claiming you answered it after me?

Comment: Right because you have been on SO for longer than me, you have more knowledge? Was going to give you benefit of the doubt but nah you're ignorant.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) which will not push a value into the array if it already exists. This code is untested, please change to fit your needs.

```
$col = "A" . $user->agencyID;
$db = $m->rules;
$collection = $db->$col;

$validValue = $_POST['validValue'];
$id = $_POST['ruleID'];

$document = array(
    'tags' => array(
            $validValue
    )
);


$collection->update(
    array(
      '_id' => new MongoId($id)
    ),
    array('$addToSet' => array('tags' => $document))
);
```